# this.stage reference causes error in flash pro

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, movieclip

My understanding was I could refer to a movie clip on the scene from AS via this.stage.movieclipname, but this keeps yielding the error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 18  1119: Access of possibly undefined property loader_obj through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.
```

The loader_obj definitely has an instance name in the properties panel, and is a symbol in the library, so what causes this, and how should I reference it in AS3?

tried linking the object to actionscript, but that caused another error.

Answer (score 0):

You should access `root` instead of `this.stage` when you are referring to pre-placed instances. This is considered bad practice, though. Like this:

```
MovieClip(root).loader_obj.x=0;
```

Linking an object to AS3 does a completely different thing: it creates a class with a provided name, so then you will be able to do `var c=new LinkedClass()` and receive an exact copy of a library movie clip or another kind of object.